# Window shortcut parameter to run program on extend display

Tags: windows, command-line, multiple-monitors

In Windows 7, is there a parameter in target line of a shortcut to run an application on second display (extend monitor)?

I saw it somewhere before, but not remember exactly how it is.

Something just like this?

```
"C:\windows\system32\calc.exe" -monitor2
```

Comment: by default, i think the system opens the program in the last monitor used before closing it. You can also change it to the next monitor by pressing Windows + Shift + LeftArrow on your keyboard

Comment: I knew that hot key but there is a way to run a program on other monitor via shortcut target parameter. Did it before, but now i really forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found.

1. If I want it on my LEFT   screen i did this: %windir%\System32\SndVol.exe -T -49490633
2. If I want it on my MIDDLE screen i did this: %windir%\System32\SndVol.exe
3. If I want it on my RIGHT  screen i did this: %windir%\System32\SndVol.exe -T 49490633

My information is only slightly modified from the following site.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/198083-volume-mixer-shortcut-create.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this commands work when creating shortcuts on windows 10.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app="https://google.com" --start-fullscreen --window-position=0,0 --new-window --user-data-dir=%TEMP%/monitor0

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app="https://yandex.com/" --start-fullscreen --window-position=1920,0 --new-window --user-data-dir=%TEMP%/monitor1 --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen

The first one starts "google.com" page in EDGE on primary monitor that is always under #0 (monitor0) and in my case was 1920x1080 started at 0x and 0y pixels.
The second one starts "yandex.com" page in EDGE on secondary monitor that is under #1 (monitor1) and in my case was also 1920x1080 started at 1921x and 0y pixels.

NOTE: There can be secondary monitor having its starting pixel in negative position in case you have secondary monitor positioned left from primary in display settings, so adjust pixels acordingly.